# Как работает super() в Java

Tags: java

Например есть код:
 Абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class Direct {

public Direct(char direct) {
    switch (direct) {
        case 'G':
            goToForward();
            break;
    }
}

abstract void goToForward();
}
```

И класс который наследуется от него:

```
public class DirectSouth extends Direct {

public DirectSouth(char direct) {
    super(direct);
}

void goToForward() {
    //какой-то код
}
```

Я не совсем могу понять как работает метод super(). Он вроде ссылается на супер класс (класс родителя) , но почему класс `goToForward()` выполняется в `Direct` , а не в `DirectSouth` ?
Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: А в каком смысле «`goToForward()` выполняется в `Direct`»? `goToForward` — виртуальная функция, вызов её в базовом классе приводит к выполнению most derived-варианта.

Comment: ваш код не скомпилируется, так как    
    void goToForward() {
        //какой-то код
    }    
не переопределяет абстрактный метод goToForward у родителя. Неабстрактный класс 100% обязан переопределить ВСЕ абстрактные методы родителя

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то перепутали. метод goToForward() класса DirectSouth выполнится, но вызывается он в базовом абстрактном классе, так как ключевое слово super это вызов конструктора базового класса.

пс. через super мы также можем сослаться на методы базового класса.
Например:

```
public abstract class Direct {

    public Direct(char direct) {
        switch (direct) {
            case 'G':
                goToForward();
                break;
        }
    }

    abstract void goToForward();

    public void directMethod(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);

    }
}

class DirectSouth extends Direct {

    public DirectSouth(char direct) {
        super(direct);
    }

    void goToForward() {
        super.directMethod("Super sends message to directMethod");
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
Super sends message to directMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае используется так называемое "динамическое связывание", то есть объект, **вызывающий** метод goToForward() определяется не на этапе компиляции, а в рантайме. 
В Вашем случае, как я понимаю, был создан экземпляр класса DirectSouth:

```
Direct directSouth = new DirectSouth('a');
```

Затем объект directSouth вызывал **переопределенный** в наследнике метод goToForward():

```
directSouth.goToForward();
```

Java находит этот метод в классе DirectSouth и вызывает его. Вы получаете строку в консоли.
Стоит отметить, что для полей и статических методов используется "статическое связывание". [Подробнее об этом](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding)